# Getting errors in update in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

Please excuse my noobs query, as I'm new to linux environment.
I'm getting errors in `sudo apt-get update`

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.playonlinux.com/dists/precise/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E0F72778C4676186
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

There was some error in this ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery, I found some suggestion after googling, it said me to remove the key by doing 
`sudo apt-get del Keyno`. I did removed that still there are some errors, now it is saying there's no public key.

Please suggest how to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the references to "http://deb.playonlinux.com...." and to "http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/..." from /etc/apt/sources.list